# What are the 'uptime' load averages out of?

Tags: uptime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does load average mean in unix/linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux)

I'm confused by the load averages produced by the '**uptime**' command. I know it might be a stupid question but what are they out of?

*(My guess is that they are out of 1)*

Answer (score 0):

> In short it is the average sum of the
>   number of processes waiting in the
>   run-queue plus the number currently
>   executing over 1, 5, and 15 minute
>   time periods.

This [page](http://www.lifeaftercoffee.com/2006/03/13/unix-load-averages-explained/) is old but explains it well enough.

Comment: I was hoping I could graph it :(

Comment: Actually you can with nagios. http://www.frank4dd.com/howto/nagios/nagiosgraph/check-load-cisco-graph.gif