# Load average for a UNIX machine

Tags: linux

Need help to understand if my CPU is overloaded.

model name: *Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4657L v2 @ 2.40GHz*

```
$ less /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3

$ less /proc/cpuinfo | grep "core id" | sort|uniq | wc -l 
4

$ less /proc/cpuinfo | grep "physical id" | sort|uniq | wc -l
1
```

siblings        : 4

Load avg is `8.97, 9.33, 9.57` (`top` command output during the peak hour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does load average mean in unix/linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your CPU is overloaded.

The numbers `8.97, 9.33, 9.57` tell how many processes on average were trying to use you CPU during the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes respectively.

Your CPU can handle up to 4 processes at a time, so the number `4` would mean full load; `2` – 50% idle; `9` (as in your case) – that there were on average 9 - 4 = 5 processes at any given time (during the respective period) waiting for the CPU. This means an overload by more than 100%.

I gave this answer to explicitly cover your case. In general your question duplicates [this one](https://superuser.com/q/23498/432690).